# Table View In Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am trying to configure a page to look something as follows - where I have a standard view controller with a table view inside of it.

[image]

I have my prototype cell denied, so I can configure these in code and add the relevant images.

However, I am trying to set the code base up to do this (i.e.) implement the required table view methods but am getting a number of errors;

[image]

Is this occurring because this only apples when you have a UITableView and not a Table in a normal view controller? If so, how do I manage my dynamic table in the code?

Thanks for your time

Comment: @Biscuit128-you were forget to write a datasource method name func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    } in your quizviewcontroller class.and don't need to be write overide from data source and delegate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `UITableView` in a viewcontroller (not in an `UITableViewController`) as you are doing it, your custom viewcontroller has to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and the `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

At least the following required functions:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    ...

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    }

}
```

Since your class is not derived from `UITableViewController` it does not `override` these functions, so remove the `override` directive.